# Is there a built in function in pandas that does the following?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have two dataframes df1 and df2. they have a column with common values but in df1['comon_values_column'] every value comes up only once while in df2['comon_values_column'] each value can come up more than once. I want to see if i can do the following with a single line and without a loop

```
for value in df2['comon_values_column']:
df2['empty_column'].loc[df2['comon_values_column']==value]=df1['other_column'].loc[df1['comon_values_column']==value]
```

i have tried to use merge but because of the size of the dataframe it is very difficult to make sure that it does exactly what i want

Comment: "because of the size of the dataframe it is very difficult to make sure that it does exactly what i want" Well, try with a smaller subset first..?

Comment: Dont worry, `merge` working well here.